# HDMI: The current input timing is not supported for Raspberry PI3

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, display

While connecting to Raspberry Pi 3 to Monitor via HDMI cable, I am getting following error on the monitor.

Error: "Current input timing is not supported by the monitor display. Please change your input timing to 1920*1080, 60Hz".

How to resolve it ?

I saw the posts which say to edit /boot/config.txt file but i have only /recovery partition not /boot. How to get the display ?

Comment: can you please post the links that says to edit /boot/config.txt?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the resolution to a better one, apparently your screen doesn't support 60fps.

Try to change it in the `sudo raspi-config`

Comment: Where? I'm not seeing any way to change resolution settings in raspi-config's Display Options, nor anywhere else.